# PHP class for FORMs (display, validate, process)

Tags: php, forms, class

I want to create very basic and simple class FORMs
here is the structure of my idea

```
class forms {

function __construct() {

}

function displayForm() {       

}

function validateForm() {       

}

function processForm() {      

}
```

It will have only text , password and hidden fields plus 1 or 2 buttons. 
NO checkboxes , radioboxes , dropdown lists, dates, ....

Need help with the displayForm part which should display empty form on first , and then redisplay with the valid fields filled and invalid empty .

In the end I want to create new forms with something like these:

```
fields = array (
fieldname1=>(fielddescription , minsize, maxsize, type , defaultvalue)
fieldname2=>(fielddescription , minsize, maxsize, type , defaultvalue)
)
```

or

```
fields = array (
field1 = array (fieldname , fielddescription , minsize, maxsize, type , defaultvalue)
field2 = array (fieldname , fielddescription , minsize, maxsize, type , defaultvalue)
)
```

or

```
form1 new form ()
form1->addnewelement()
form1->addnewelement()
```

or

```
form4 new form ()
form4->addtextfield 
form4->addpassfield
form4->addhidden
form4->addsubmit
```

I'm open to all your ideas (specially a more proper way) . Thank you in advance.
P.s : no javascript.

Comment: Think of this in the form of responsibilities. Is it the `Form` object's responsibility to validate itself? Probably not, it's the job of a `Validator` object.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass the form data with POST you can first validate the data and then display the valid data in the fields you created.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Zend_Form features? You can use it without using Zend Framework itself. 
See more info here http://www.leftjoin.net/2011/03/using-zend_form-as-standalone-component/